# how to fetch URL data

Tags: php

i have created custom query which i am sending via POST ajax but problem with it is that how to retrieve that data

i am sending this query = `rep_id=4&filter=&filter_val=&rep_id=5&filter=&filter_val=&rep_id=6&filter=&filter_val=&from=p_employee_mst`

and here is the function to fetch that query in PHP

```
$rep="";
foreach ($_POST["rep_id"] as $k => $v) {
    $rep[]=$v;
}
print_r($rep);
```

i am getting following error

**Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

if print_r($_POST); i am getting this

```
Array
(
    [rep_id] => 6
    [filter] => 
    [filter_val] => 
    [from] => p_employee_mst
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example **rep_id** is a simple integer value. When you put more then one parameter to your variable you get the last one. in Your case its **rep_id=6**.

If you want an array then make an array in your request.

```
rep_id[]=5&rep_id[]=6
```

then you get as result:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '5' (length=1)
  1 => string '6' (length=1)
```

And then you can iterate over the array. Otherwise you get the following result:

```
rep_id=5&rep_id=6

string '6' (length=1)
```

Because the last value / parameter win.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in you're Query String

`rep_id` should be represend as `rep_id[]` ,and you should replace it in link as URL Encoded something like : `rep_id%5B%5D`